# Drag and drop is not happening in Cypress.io test

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, cypress

I am trying to drag an element and then drop it into a drop zone area, but the test is not performing the drag and drop action in Cypress.io. It would be really helpful if someone could advise about the potential issue here. There are no errors throwing, but still, the drag and drop is not happening here.

```
describe('Verify the drag and drop test', function() {

  it.only('Check whether the drag and drop of an item is working fine', function() {

  cy.visit('http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-and-drop-demo.html')  

    const MyDataTransfer = function () {};
    const dt = new MyDataTransfer ();
    dt.types = [];

    // cy.wait(3000);

    cy.get('#todrag span')
      .contains('Draggable 1')
      .trigger("draggable", {dataTransfer: dt});

    cy.get("#todrag span")
      .contains('Draggable 1')
      .trigger('mousedown', { which: 1, pageX: 600, pageY: 600 })
      .trigger('mousemove', { which: 1, clientX: 330, clientY: 35 });

    cy.wait(3000);

    cy.get('#mydropzone')
      .trigger("dropzone", {dataTransfer: dt});                     
  });   
});
```

[image]

Comment: Any advice on the drag and drop issue in Cypress.io test ?

Comment: Couldn't make it work (their DnD seems a mess), but you're triggering `draggable`/`dropzone` events which don't seem to be bound on either of those elements, so there's that.

Comment: Later, I have tried something less complicated and it is working. But I am looking forward from cypress team to have the DnD in the next major release which should be in a better state.

Comment: You can paste your working code for this example into your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few changes should achieve what you are looking for. Here's a breakdown of steps taken to solve this question...

First off, instead of stubbing out `MyDataTransfer`, just construct a new [**DataTransfer**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/DataTransfer) object, which comes packed with the necessary properties and methods needed for drag events:

```
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer;
```

Next, it's best to trigger [native drop and drag events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API#Drag_Events), as opposed to `draggable` and `dropzone`.  Selenium Easy is listening for `dragstart`, `dragend`, and `drop` (you can see this inside of their [drag-and-drop-demo.js source file](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/js/drag-and-drop-demo.js)). Put these inside of a helper function, to be called later inside the test:

```
function dndIt() {
  cy.get('#todrag span:first-of-type')
    .trigger('dragstart', { dataTransfer });

  cy.get('#mydropzone')
    .trigger('drop', { dataTransfer });

  cy.get('#todrag span:first-of-type')
    .trigger('dragend');               // <-- seleniumeasy listens for this...
}                                      // otherwise, draggables are copied.
```

A `beforeEach` block is helpful for setting the viewport and visiting the application:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  cy.viewport(1000, 600);
  cy.visit('https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-and-drop-demo.html');
});
```

And finally, the test block calls the helper function, and asserts that the item was dragged and dropped:

```
it('Check whether the drag and drop of an item is working fine', function() {
  dndIt();

  cy.get('#droppedlist')
    .should(($el) => {
      expect($el.children()).to.have.lengthOf(1)
    });
});
```

Here's the solution in its entirety:

```
describe('Verify the drag and drop test', function() {
  const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer;

  function dndIt() {
    cy.get('#todrag span:first-of-type')
      .trigger('dragstart', { dataTransfer });

    cy.get('#mydropzone')
      .trigger('drop', { dataTransfer });

    cy.get('#todrag span:first-of-type')
      .trigger('dragend');               // <-- seleniumeasy listens for this...
  }                                      // if left out, draggables are copied.

  beforeEach(function() {
    cy.viewport(1000, 600);
    cy.visit('https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-and-drop-demo.html');
  });

  it('Check whether the drag and drop of an item is working fine', function() {
    dndIt();

    cy.get('#droppedlist')
      .should(($el) => {
        expect($el.children()).to.have.lengthOf(1)
      });
  });
});
```

[image]

The [**drag_n_drop_spec.js**](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/testing-dom__drag-drop/cypress/integration/drag_n_drop_spec.js) provided in the [**cypress-example-recipes repo**](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes) was a helpful resource.

Comment: Awesome!  I have updated my cypress version to 3.1.4 ..it's all working now. Thanks, mate. Accepting the answer.

Comment: One last question if I need to drag second item `Draggable 2` ...how can we change here `span:first-of-type`

Comment: Got it ! I have used `cy.get('#todrag span:contains("Draggable 2")')`..all good now

Comment: A gotcha to understand: when you trigger events in the test code, there is a difference compared to triggering them naturally. For instance, if you don't provide `dataTransfer` via `cy.contains('foo').trigger('dragstart', { dataTransfer: new DataTransfer() })`, your `dragstart` handler which relies on having the `dataTransfer` property of the event will break. And then in your `dragend` event you have to provide the data that your app's `dragstart` handler might have hooked onto `.dataTransfer`. That introduces fragile coupling between the tests and the app. (Not that there is a better way...)